# How to create a wedge shape out of content in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am looking to create the following shape using divs and CSS on a website and really struggling?

[Example of shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yecx8.jpg)

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A perspective [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) will get you there:

```css
.wedge {
  margin: 15px;
  transform: perspective(700px) rotateY(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<img class="wedge" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
```